# pgf/TikZ: environment pgfinterruptclipping?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to interrupt clipping? In other words: Does anything similar to the pgfinterruptboundingbox environment exist? I tried it with the pgfinterruptpath environment and am a bit surprised that this does not work.

Here comes the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}
  \clip (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \draw (1,1) circle (0.5cm);
%  \begin{pgfinterruptclipping}
   \node at (1,2.5) {This is a circle!};
%  \end{pgfinterruptclipping}
  \draw (0.5,0.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** Of course I can split the scope in several parts, but it would be far more elegant and less tedious to shortly skip out of the path. If there is no 'simple' solution, this is totally ok for me! No need for lengthy investigations.

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to do with this environment? Clipping is valid inside a particular scope. You can still draw anything outside it.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. I have to draw a larger picture with a sequential structure, which I want to show step-by-step with beamer. Some text is outside of the clipping area and I do not want to leave the clipping scope each time, as the clipping scope and the \visible-steps are not correlated.

Comment: Do you know that `\draw` is beamer-aware? You can insert step indicators (`<1->`). I'm not sure how it works inside a clipping path, but may be can help you.

Comment: The problem will perhaps be, that I regularly use the relative <+-> indicator, as I do not know, whether there will be some other material in this frame before the picture.

Comment: Indeed can you show a small example or MWE?